# Scaling down the sensitivity of an MEMS mic

Tags: sound, mems

I'm using an MEMS mic [ADMP401](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADMP401.pdf), and the datasheet said, that the sensitivity form the chip is -46dbV, my question, how to can the scale it down, mean that I hear only really loud sounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sensitivity of -46dBV means that with an incident sound level of 94dB (SPL) at 1kHz, the device's voltage output is 5mV. For the record, 94dB SPL is 1 pascal RMS of sound pressure.

If you read the data sheet it also tells you that the absolute maximum level of sound it can withstand is 160 dB SPL and this is very loud. At this level of SPL it is likely that the device's output will be heavily distorted.

It might help if you read [this document](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/application_notes/AN-1112.PDF). It's also from AD and is entitled AN-1112, Microphone Specifications Explained. It contains this:-

> For digital microphones, a full-scale signal is defined as the highest
>   signal level that can be output from the microphone; for Analog
>   Devices MEMS microphones, this level is 120 to 140 dB SPL. See the
>   Acoustic Overload Point section for a fuller description of this
>   signal level.

120 dB SPL can be assumed to be resolvable from the MEMs device and indeed, in the device spec it says: -

> Maximum Acoustic Input Peak 120 dB SPL

I think it has been established that 120 dB SPL is the maximum sound level that the device can linearly reproduce an output voltage that is relatively free from distortion. Is 120dB loud enough (?): -

[image]

If you need something that will work over 120dB SPL maybe you should consider a different microphone technology or find a way of mechanically reducing the sounds received by the sensor. If 120dB SPL is OK then read on...

If you only want to hear loud sounds and by this I mean you want smaller sounds not to register at all then, you can build an electronic circuit that is called a [noise-gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_gate). Basically a noise gate is a regular amplifier that can be disabled (or muted) when the input signal level is lower than a predetermined (and usually adjustable) threshold: -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look up something called a *resistor divider*.  That is something that scales down a voltage with a fixed gain between 0 and 1.  However, that will scale all sounds the same amount.  There will be no threshold between whatever you consider loud and soft sounds.

To give detials of the divider would require a more detailed question, like what the output will be connected to and what voltage that signal will be considered "loud" at.